# Cannot perform data driven testing using excel in python robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

**ERROR:**[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: ImportError: Requirements (pandas, numpy) for XLS support are not installed.  Use 'pip install -U robotframework-datadriver[XLS]' to install XLS support.

**I have already use "pip install -U robotframework-datadriver[XLS]" this command in cmd.
But it tells requirement is already satisfied.
I want use excel for data driven testing. Can anybody help on this?**
I'm looking for the solution.

Cmd tells:

```
C:\Users\soham.amin>pip install -U robotframework-datadriver[XLS]
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-datadriver[XLS] in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework>=3.1 in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (1.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd>=1.0.0 in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pandas->robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pandas->robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\soham.amin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas->robotframework-datadriver[XLS]) (1.15.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to use virtual envrionments because:

- you don't polute your user or global space
- you can easily install a different version of a package than you have installed elsewhere
- if something goes wrong, you can easily remove the whole virtual environment and start again with a clean installation

I don't see you're using a virtual environment, so I recommend you do just that, e.g. with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv):

```
$ python -m venv my-project
$ source my-project/bin/activate
```

From now on, your prompt changes and you're inside the virtual environment. You can now use pip just like you did, but all packages and modules installed from within the virtual environment will be installed just there in this one virtual environment.

All this might solve your problem because if I'm not mistaken, you installed those packages and modules somewhere where Python interpreter can't see them.